# Is Firefox covered under warranty?

Tags: firefox

When editing using about::config it warns that I'll void the warranty. What's this warranty about?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just a joke the people over at Mozilla made. It doesn't actually void your computer warranty. It just means be careful of what you change.

Comment: is there a backstory?

Comment: As far as I know nope. It's just a joke they put in their product. Some companies do this. Like google for example. http://www.google.com/onceuponatime/tisp/

Comment: TiSP was simply Google's April Fools' Day hoax. It's become an [annual tradition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Google%27s_hoaxes_and_easter_eggs#April_Fool.27s_Hoaxes) now, getting more complex by the year with all services joining in with their own versions.

Comment: BTW, the [official Mozilla description](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config#Opening_about:config) is: "If you see a page with the warning message, *This might void your warranty!*, click the button labeled "I'll be careful, I promise!", to continue (**in fact, there is no warranty whatsoever, it's more a joke to ensure that users are aware of what they are about to do**). *Use the checkbox there to avoid the warning in the future.*"

Comment: It is also [deliberately intended to turn away people who didn't get the joke](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=446704#c19).